# Moving multiple divs or elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to move the anchor tag into the div with the class "name" at a specific breakpoint.

This is the current HTML. The problem is that I have 6 "profiles" that need to do the same.

```
<div class="profile">
  <div class="name">
     <p>Name</p>
  </div>
  <div class="email">
     <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

All of the solutions I've tried will put all 6 of the anchor tags in each div with class "name". Like this multiplied 6 times:

```
<div class="profile">
<div class="name">
    <p>Name</p>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
</div>
<div class="email">
    <a href="example@email.com">example@email.com</a>
</div>
```

How do I move each anchor tag relative to it's "profile"?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: what you have exactly done for this....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate `.profile` block using [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and then target desired element using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Here in example I have used [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/).

```js
$('.profile').each(function() {
  $(this).find('.email a').appendTo($(this).find('.name'));
  $(this).find('.email').remove(); //If you need to remove
});


console.log($('.container').html()) //For debugging
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Name 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <a href="example@email.com">example1@email.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="name">
      <p>Name 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <a href="example2@email.com">example2@email.com</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```